# How to let users backup their posts to Google drive from Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

Is it possible to let individual users backup their posts to their google drive from a Rails app?

Is there anyone who has done something like this.

User should be able to backup their posts at an interval of their choice(daily, weekly, etc). And also can restore their backups from the Rails app itself, in case of data loss.

Comment: [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/ruby) and [this](https://github.com/gimite/google-drive-ruby) should get you started

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible.

Define "something like this". Do you mean saved something to Google Drive from a rails app? Sure, there's a gem for that. Do you mean saved posts to Google Drive? If so, that's not so different than saving anything else to Google Drive. You just need to serialize the records into a document then upload.

For automated backup look into background and cron jobs. If during load to Google Drive you've serialized the records effectively, restore should be relatively trivial.